# Do women study Torah in the afterlife?

Tags: women, olam-haba-world-to-come

Chazal are replete with stories about the Yeshiva Shel Maala (heavenly yeshiva) whereby the souls of the righteous deceased study Torah.

What do women do in the afterlife? Is there also a similar system for them?

Comment: Could you might give one source for the many places that Chazal speak about learning in the Yeshiva Shel Maala?

Comment: @Yehoshua or that the Yeshiva Shel Maala is a study hall at all http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78045/759

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Eliyahu Mansour, based on the Zohar HaQadosh, says that there are also yeshivot for women Upstairs.

While I unfortunately cannot find Rabbi Mansour's *derashah* at present, [here is a Hebrew article](http://www.hidabroot.org/article/80032) from Hidabroot.org touching on the same subjects.

Comment: Do you have a link or name of a source where he says that, so that we don't have to just rely on your word?

Comment: I've racked my brain today to no avail trying to remember in which *derashah* Rabbi Mansour discusses this. If memory serves, he does not mention exactly where in the Zohar HaQadosh this appears.