# What is the Yeshiva Shel Maala?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, yeshiva-school, soul, heaven

What is the "yeshiva shel maala" (literally yeshiva on high) that is found a number of times in Chazal's writings (ex. "whoever teaches his fellow's son Torah merits and sits in the yeshiva on High" - Baba Metzia 85a)?

Is this some kind of analogy for something or is there an actual Beit Midrash (in spiritual form) where souls upstairs sit and learn torah like yeshivas here on earth?

Comment: Beautiful question. I wonder, also, if this has anything to do with the yeshiva where one learns Torah before birth

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct. If there is additional information you are looking for, consider clarifying what it is.

Answer (score 4):

Ramban writes the following in Sha'ar Hag'mul of his Torat Ha'adam:

> שכר הנפשות וקיומם בעולם הנשמות נקרא לרבותינו גן עדן, ופעמים קורין אותו עליה וישיבה של מעלה
>
> The reward for souls, and their existence in the Realm of the Souls, is called by our rabbis: "Garden of Eden", and sometimes they call it "Ascent", and "Yeshiva Shel Ma'alah".

That is, "yeshiva shel ma'alah" is just one of the terms used to refer to the after-life.

Perhaps he understands the term "yeshiva" in the Biblical sense of "dwelling", rather than the rabbinic usage of an academy.

Comment: Support for that last statement can be found in the intro to Kol Nidrei which compares ישיבה של מעלה with ישיבה של מטה which doesn't mean an academy.

Comment: thanks..+1 that gm regarding yehuda who was in nidui does seem to be some sort of learning. it says he understood nothing then in the end halacha like him

Comment: perhaps gan eden, ascent itself is a metaphor for a yeshiva. whereas the yeshiva shel maala is literal

Comment: @ray That is an excellent point. Indeed, I suspect that the term _m'tivta d'raqia_ itself, assumes that the intent of _yeshiva shel ma'ala_ refers to a heavenly academy. Presumably, one advocating the position implied by Ramban would have to say the term evolved.

Comment: While your first point was valid `perhaps gan eden, ascent itself is a metaphor for a yeshiva` Seems completely contrived and does not fit the wording of Ramban at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA: Three men collect to form a beis din to permit davening with sinners on Yom Kippur, and call themselves the yeshiva shel mata. By parallel, there is no proof from this citation that the yehiva shel maala is a "dwelling place on high" that contains a court that similarly permits, rather than the court itself, or a beis medrash (yeshiva) that holds court, etc...

Comment: @MichaBerger No. I'm not going to silently allow you to stick "or a beis medrash (yeshiva) that holds court," as if that is at all reasonable. First off, you have no evidence they call themselves the YSM, instead of the place they represent (parallel to Makom/Kahal in the previous line). But anyway even if they are the Yeshiva, that just means "sitting" or "convocation" (like במותב תלתא), which is the original root meaning, not academy. Perhaps "dwelling" was too broad for ישב, but my point stands that it doesn't mean academy!

Comment: @DoubleAA: How is it unreasonable to think that a tefillah that well-post-dates Chazal used "yeshiva shel ma'alah" and "yeshiva shel mata" meaning "yeshiva" in Chazal's sense of the word? I think that third option is unreasonable for another reason -- when in shul or ad-hoc minyan, the 3 serving as dayanim are not necessarily representing a yeshiva, and yet "yeshiva shel mata" is still said. Still, they could be talking about the "beis din" itself, rather than all denizens of Shamayim.

Comment: Sorry for the lazy comment, but isn't there somewhere in Makkos (11?) which talks about Yehuda not being admitted to the Yeshiva shel Maala because his bones weren't assembled in a skeleton (then Moshe fixed them and davened that Hashem let him in) - this suggests that it is more than just Gan Eden that everyone goes to.

Comment: Sota 7 same story:

"1.Moshe: Yehudah caused Reuven to admit. (Is it proper that Reuven is intact,) "and this is to Yehudah" (that his bones are rolling)?!

2.Moshe continued: "Hear, Hash-m, the voice of Yehudah" - his bones came together, but he was denied entrance to the Yeshiva in Shamayim.

3."Bring him to his nation" - he was allowed in, but he could not understand the arguments.

4."His hands are great for him" - he could understand, but he could not reach the correct law.

5."He will have help from his adversaries" (he reached the correct Halachah)."

Answer (score 1):

The Talmud in a number of other places, and different contexts, mentions the so-called Heavenly Academy (מתיבתא דרקיע or ישיבה של מעלה). As you can see from the citations below, it appears to be a place where people go after death, it usually seems to involve Torah study, and on at least one occasion it included a debate with God about Torah Law.

**Berachos 18b**

> דאבוה דשמואל הוו קא מפקדי גביה זוזי דיתמי כי נח נפשיה לא הוה שמואל
>   גביה הוו קא קרו ליה בר אכיל זוזי דיתמי אזל אבתריה לחצר מות אמר להו
>   בעינא אבא אמרו ליה אבא טובא איכא הכא אמר להו בעינא אבא בר אבא אמרו ליה
>   אבא בר אבא נמי טובא איכא הכא אמר להו בעינא אבא בר אבא אבוה דשמואל היכא
>   אמרו ליה סליק למתיבתא דרקיעא אדהכי חזייה ללוי דיתיב אבראי אמר ליה אמאי
>   יתבת אבראי מאי טעמא לא סלקת אמר ליה דאמרי לי כל כי הנך שני דלא סליקת
>   למתיבתא דרבי אפס ואחלישתיה לדעתיה לא מעיילינן לך למתיבתא דרקיעא אדהכי
>   והכי אתא אבוה חזייה דהוה קא בכי ואחיך אמר ליה מאי טעמא קא בכית אמר ליה
>   דלעגל קא אתית מאי טעמא אחיכת דחשיבת בהאי עלמא טובא אמר ליה אי חשיבנא
>   נעיילוה ללוי ועיילוהו ללוי
>
> The father of Samuel had some money belonging to orphans deposited
>   with him. When he died, Samuel was not with him, and they called him,
>   ‘The son who consumes the money of orphans’. So he went after his
>   father to the cemetery, and said to them [the dead]. I am looking for
>   Abba. They said to him: There are many Abbas here. I want Abba b.
>   Abba, he said. They replied: There are also several Abbas b. Abba
>   here. He then said to them: I Want Abba b. Abba the father of Samuel;
>   where is he? They replied: He has gone up to the Academy of the Sky.
>   Meanwhile he saw Levi sitting outside. He said to him: Why are you
>   sitting outside? Why have you not gone up [to heaven]? He replied:
>   Because they said to me: For as many years as you did not go up to the
>   academy of R. Efes and hurt his feelings, we will not let you go up to
>   the Academy of the Sky. Meanwhile his father came. Samuel observed
>   that he was both weeping and laughing. He said to him: Why are you
>   weeping? He replied: Because you are coming here soon. And why are you
>   laughing? Because you are highly esteemed in this world. He thereupon
>   said to him: If I am esteemed, let them take up Levi; and they did
>   take up Levi. ([Soncino translation.](https://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf))

**Bava Metzia 85b**

> אמר ר' זירא אמש נראה לי ר' יוסי בר' חנינא אמרתי לו אצל מי אתה תקוע אמר
>   לי אצל ר' יוחנן ור' יוחנן אצל מי אצל ר' ינאי ור' ינאי אצל מי אצל ר'
>   חנינא ור' חנינא אצל מי אצל ר' חייא אמרתי לו ור' יוחנן אצל ר' חייא לא
>   אמר לי באתר דזקוקין דנורא ובעורין דאשא מאן מעייל בר נפחא לתמן אמר רב
>   חביבא אשתעי לי רב חביבא בר סורמקי חזי ליה ההוא מרבנן דהוה שכיח אליהו
>   גביה דלצפרא הוו שפירן עיניה ולאורתא דמיין כדמיקלין בנורא אמרי ליה מאי
>   האי ואמר לי דאמרי ליה לאליהו אחוי לי רבנן כי סלקי למתיבתא דרקיע אמר לי
>   בכולהו מצית לאסתכולי בהו לבר מגוהרקא דר' חייא דלא תסתכל ביה מאי
>   סימנייהו בכולהו אזלי מלאכי כי סלקי ונחתי לבר מגוהרקא דר' חייא דמנפשיה
>   סליק ונחית לא מצאי לאוקמא אנפשאי אסתכלי בה אתו תרי בוטיטי דנורא
>   ומחיוהו לההוא גברא וסמינהו לעיניה למחר אזלי אשתטחי אמערתיה אמינא
>   מתנייתא דמר מתנינא ואתסאי
>
> R. Zera said: Last night R. Jose son of R. Hanina appeared to me [in a
>   dream], and I asked him, ‘Near whom art thou seated [in the Heavenly
>   Academy]?’ — ‘Near R. Johanan.’ ‘And R. Johanan near whom?’ — ‘R.
>   Jannai.’ ‘And R. Jannai?’ — ‘Near R. Hanina.’ ‘And R. Hanina?’ — ‘Near
>   R. Hiyya.’ Said I to him, ‘And is not R. Johanan [worthy of a seat]
>   near R. Hiyya?’ — He replied, ‘In the region of fiery sparks and
>   flaming tongues, who will let the smith's son enter?
>
> R. Habiba said: R. Habiba b. Surmakia told me: I saw one of the
>   Rabbis whom Elijah used to frequent, whose eyes were clear in the
>   morning, but in the evening they looked as though burnt in fire. I
>   questioned him, ‘What is the meaning of this?’ And he answered me
>   [thus]: ‘I requested Elijah to shew me the [departed] Rabbis as they
>   ascend to the Heavenly Academy. He replied: "Thou canst look upon all,
>   excepting the carriage of R. Hiyya: upon it thou shalt not look."
>   "What is their sign?" "All are accompanied by angels when they ascend
>   and descend, excepting R. Hiyya's carriage, who ascends and descends
>   of his own accord." But unable to control my desire, I gazed upon it,
>   whereat two fiery streams issued forth, smote and blinded me in one
>   eye. The following day I went and prostrated myself upon his grave,
>   crying out, "It is thy Baraitha that I study!" and I was healed.’ ([Soncino translation.](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nezikin/Baba_Metzia.pdf))

While the second part of this passage uses the term Mesivta D'rakia, the first part does not use the term Mesivta D'rakia or Yeshiva Shel Ma'alah. However, Rashi identifies the first part with the Yeshiva Shel Ma'alah.

**Bava Metzia 86a**

> קא מיפלגי במתיבתא דרקיעא אם בהרת קודמת לשער לבן טמא ואם שער לבן קודם
>   לבהרת טהור ספק הקב"ה אומר טהור וכולהו מתיבתא דרקיעא אמרי טמא ואמרי מאן
>   נוכח נוכח רבה בר נחמני דאמר רבה בר נחמני אני יחיד בנגעים אני יחיד
>   באהלות שדרו שליחא בתריה לא הוה מצי מלאך המות למקרב ליה מדלא הוה קא
>   פסיק פומיה מגרסיה אדהכי נשב זיקא ואויש ביני קני סבר גונדא דפרשי הוא
>   אמר תינח נפשיה דההוא גברא ולא ימסר בידא דמלכותא כי הוה קא ניחא נפשיה
>   אמר טהור טהור יצאת בת קול ואמרה אשריך רבה בר נחמני שגופך טהור ויצאתה
>   נשמתך בטהור נפל פתקא מרקיעא בפומבדיתא רבה בר נחמני נתבקש בישיבה של
>   מעלה
>
> Now, they were disputing in the Heavenly Academy thus: If the bright
>   spot preceded the white hair, he is unclean; if the reverse, he is
>   clean. If [the order is] in doubt — the Holy One, blessed be He,
>   ruled, He is clean; whilst the entire Heavenly Academy maintained, He
>   is unclean. Who shall decide it? said they. — Rabbah b. Nahmani; for
>   he said, I am pre-eminent in the laws of leprosy and tents. A
>   messenger was sent for him, but the Angel of Death could not
>   approach him, because he did not interrupt his studies [even for a
>   moment]. In the meantime, a wind blew and caused a rustling in the
>   bushes, when he imagined it to be a troop of soldiers. ‘Let me die,’
>   he exclaimed, ‘rather than be delivered into the hands of the State.
>   As he was dying, he exclaimed, ‘Clean, clean!’ when a Heavenly Voice
>   cried out, ‘Happy art thou, O Rabbah b. Nahmani, whose body is pure
>   and whose soul had departed in purity!’ A missive fell from Heaven in
>   Pumbeditha, [upon which was written,] ‘Rabbah b. Nahmani has been
>   summoned by the Heavenly Academy. ([Soncino translation.](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nezikin/Baba_Metzia.pdf))

**Makkos 11b**

> אמר רב יהודה אמר רב נידוי על תנאי צריך הפרה מנלן מיהודה דכתיב אם לא
>   הביאותיו אליך וגו' וא"ר שמואל בר נחמני א"ר יונתן מאי דכתיב יחי ראובן
>   ואל ימות וגו' וזאת ליהודה כל אותן מ' שנה שהיו ישראל במדבר עצמותיו של
>   יהודה היו מגולגלין בארון עד שעמד משה ובקש עליו רחמים אמר לפניו רבונו
>   של עולם מי גרם לראובן שיודה יהודה וזאת ליהודה שמע ה' קול יהודה עאל
>   איבריה לשפא לא הוה קא מעיילי ליה למתיבתא דרקיע ואל עמו תביאנו לא הוה
>   קא ידע למישקל ומיטרח בשמעתא בהדי רבנן ידיו רב לו לא הוה ידע לפרוקי
>   קושיא ועזר מצריו תהיה
>
> Rab Judah reported Rab to have said that a conditional exclusion [even
>   if self-imposed] requires [formal] absolution. Whence is this derived?
>   — From [the fate of] Judah, for it is written, And Judah said to
>   Israel his father. ‘Send the lad [Benjamin] with me . . . if I bring
>   him not unto thee . . then let me bear the blame for ever.’ And [on
>   this theme]. R. Samuel b. Nahmani repeated how [his Master] R.
>   Jonathan said: What are [the allusions in] the text, Let Reuben live
>   and not die; and let not his men be few. And this [is] unto Judah, and
>   he [Moses] said, Lord, hear the voice of Judah and bring him unto his
>   people; let his hands be sufficient for him and be Thou an help to him
>   from his enemies? All through the forty years that israel remained in
>   the wilderness, Judah's bones were jolted about in their coffin until
>   [in the end] Moses stood up and supplicated for mercy on his behalf:
>   Lord of the Universe! [said he.] Who influenced Reuben to make free
>   confession [of his guilt]? Was it not Judah? ‘and this [was due] to
>   Judah! And he [Moses] said, Lord, hear the voice [appeal] of Judah.’
>   Thereupon, joint slipped Into socket. Judah, not having yet been
>   ushered in to the Celestial College. [Moses again prayed] — ‘and bring
>   him unto his people’! Judah, being unable to parry in debate [through
>   prolonged absence, Moses prayed] — ‘let his hands [capacity] be
>   sufficient for him’; being unable to disentangle [analyse or explain]
>   intricate points raised in discussion, Moses prayed — ‘and be Thou an
>   help unto him from his adversaries’. ([Soncino translation.](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nezikin/Makkoth.pdf))

Additionally, in the Midrash of the Ten Executed by the Government, there are two statements about R. Akiva expounding Torah in the Heavenly Academy to the souls of the righteous:

> ואחריו הוציאו את רבי עקיבא בן יוסף הדורש כתרי אותיות ומגלה פנים בתורה
>   כמו שנמסרו למשה מסיני וכשהוציאוהו להריגה בא מכתב לקיסר שמלך ערביא
>   מתפשט בארצו והיה נחוץ ללכת וצוה לחבוש את ר"ע בבית האסורין עד שישוב מן
>   המלחמה וכשבא מן המלחמה צוה להוציאו וסרקו את בשרו במסרקות של ברזל ובכל
>   סריקה וסריקה שהיו סורקין היה אומר ר"ע צדיק הוא ה' הצור תמים פעלו כי כל
>   דרכיו משפט אל אמונה ואין עול צדיק וישר הוא יצתה ב"ק ואמרה אשריך ר'
>   עקיבא שהיית צדיק וישר ויצאה נשמתך בצדיק וישר וכשנפטר בא אליהו הנביא
>   זכור לטוב ונטלו על כתפו ונשאו חמש פרסאות ופגע בו ר' יהושע הגרסי א"ל
>   וכי אינך כהן א"ל גופו של צדיק אינו מטמא והלך עמו ר' יהושע הגרסי עד
>   שהגיע למערה אחת יפה מאד וכיון שנכנסו שם מצאו מטה יפה ונר דלוק נטלו
>   אליהו ז"ל דרך מראשותיו ור' יהושע דרך מרגלותיו והשכיבוהו על אותו מטה
>   והיו מלאכי השרת בוכים עליו שלשה ימים ושלשה לילות ואח"כ קברוהו באותה
>   מערה וביום שלמחרתו נטלו אליהו ז"ל והביאו בישיבה של מעלה לדרוש שם בכתרי
>   אותיות והיו מתקבצות כל הנשמות של הצדיקים וחסידים לשמוע מדרשותיווביום
>   שלמחרתו נטלו אליהו ז"ל והביאו בישיבה של מעלה לדרוש שם בכתרי אותיות
>   והיו מתקבצות כל הנשמות של הצדיקים וחסידים לשמוע מדרשותיו

.

> ואחריו הוציאו את ר' אלעזר בן שמוע אמרו עליו שאותו היום היה בן מאה וחמש
>   שנים ומקטנותו ועד סוף ימיו לא שמע אדם שהוציא תיפלות מפיו ולא נתקוטט עם
>   חביריו בין בדבור בין במעשה והיה עניו ושפל רוח וישב בתענית שמונים שנה
>   ואותו היום שנהרג יום כפורים היה ובאו תלמידיו לפניו ואמרו לו רבינו מה
>   אתה רואה אמר להם אני רואה את ר' יהודה בן בבא שמשיאים את מטתו ומטת ר"ע
>   בן יוסף סמוכה אצלו והם מתווכחים בדבר הלכה יחד זה עם זה אמרו לו ומי
>   הכריע ביניהם אמר להם ר' ישמעאל כ"ג אמרו לו מי מנצח אמר להם ר"ע על שטרח
>   בכל כחו בתורה אמר להם בניי רואה אני עוד שנשמת כל צדיק וצדיק מטהרת את
>   עצמה במי השלוח כדי ליכנס היום בטהרה בישיבה של מעלה לשמוע את דרשות ר"ע
>   בן יוסף שידרש להם מענינו של יום

This is all assuming that we take the above texts at face value. One might wish to argue, however, that these are not literal descriptions, but Aggadic passages reflecting some deeper meaning.